# Domain redirects to wrong site in nginx, multiple sites in config files

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, php-fpm

I have 2 websites setup on nginx, and the correct one should load depending on which domain is accessed.

For example:
website1.com
website2.com

However, when accessing either of these domains, they both load website1.com.

What's wrong with my configs? Both configs are in separate files in sites-enabled

website1.com config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/website1.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name website1.com;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
    #location /RequestDenied {
    #   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;    
    #}

    #error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    #location = /50x.html {
    #   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #   # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    #
    #   # With php5-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php5-fpm:
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    #   fastcgi_index index.php;
    #   include fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}
```

website2.com config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/website2.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name website2.com;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
    #location /RequestDenied {
    #   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;    
    #}

    #error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    #location = /50x.html {
    #   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #   # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    #
    #   # With php5-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php5-fpm:
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    #   fastcgi_index index.php;
    #   include fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}
```

nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 4096;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    #sendfile on;
    #tcp_nopush on;
    #tcp_nodelay on;
    #keepalive_timeout 10;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

ssl_ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS";
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;


    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##
access_log off; 
log_not_found off; 
error_log /var/log/nginx-error.log warn;
    #access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    #error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
gzip_vary on; 
gzip_proxied any; 
gzip_comp_level 6; 
gzip_min_length 1100; 
gzip_buffers 16 8k; 
gzip_http_version 1.1; 
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

open_file_cache max=2000 inactive=20s; 
open_file_cache_valid 60s; 
open_file_cache_min_uses 5; 
open_file_cache_errors off;
client_max_body_size 50M; 
client_body_buffer_size 1m; 
client_body_timeout 15; 
client_header_timeout 15; 
keepalive_timeout 2 2; 
send_timeout 15; 
sendfile on; 
tcp_nopush on; 
tcp_nodelay on;
fastcgi_buffers 256 16k; 
fastcgi_buffer_size 128k; 
fastcgi_connect_timeout 3s; 
fastcgi_send_timeout 120s; 
fastcgi_read_timeout 120s; 
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k; 
fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k; 
reset_timedout_connection on; 
server_names_hash_bucket_size 100;

}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Comment: Are you entering www in front of the site name in the browser when you access the site?

Comment: Now that you mention it, it only does the incorrect redirection if the 'www' is included. If it is just the domain, it works as expected. Thoughts?

Comment: Do you have a default server config?

Comment: Hi @Drifter104 - I've added nginx.conf to the original question just now :)

Comment: Hi Mark, sorry poor choice of words I meant a default site config. In the sites-enabled or conf.d directory you should have a config called default. Do you have have one?

Comment: All good mate @Drifter104 - no I deleted that one, it has only one for each of the 2 websites

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If there is no default site config then nginx will auto select the first available config file when presented with a request it doesn't have specifically configured.

In this case when you add the www in front of either domain nginx is selecting **website1.com config**

To resolve this particular issue replace the following lines of the configs

**website1.com config**

```
  server_name website1.com www.website1.com;
```

**website2.com config**

```
  server_name website2.com www.website2.com;
```

You can alternatively use `*.website1.com or *.website2.com` to capture all requests.

You should really have a default site config though as there are a few quirks like this that can be avoided by having one. Even if it simply does a 400 error return.

Comment: Thank you for that! I only had website.com set up in nginx but my domain was set up at registrar level to automatically convert website.com to www.website.com...

Comment: Just adding the result of my own bad experience here: this issue can also happen if you do not provide an ssl configuration for a domain. Suppose you have only a http configuration enabled for a site, but some web browser tries to reach it using https... since nginx doesn't provide a default site with ssl enabled, you will stumble upon a variant of this issue. You must add a default site with ssl enabled to fix.

Comment: I've tried this but unlucky

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned in one of the comment, I was also facing a similar issue. I'd setup 2 Flask apps and a Node.js app on my local Linux Ubuntu server and had setup sub-domains for each site. The Node.js app was the last and for some reason showed one of the Flask apps instead. I'd used certbot for the SSL's for the Flask apps but nothing for the node app as was still testing it. Once I setup certbot on all 3 apps nginx was showing the 3 sites correctly.

TLDR - install SSL on all your domains/sub-domains and nginx will play nicely.